# Does anyone know any good examples of arraylist representations of Queue and Stack implementations/operations?

Tags: java, arraylist, stack, queue, implementation

Does anyone know of any good examples of arraylist representations of Queue and Stack and implementations of relevant operations/methods in Java?

Any help gratefully recieved.

Answer (score 1):

[`ArrayBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) is an array list implementation of `Queue`. (The [documentation of `Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) lists many implementations.)

[`Stack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) is actually a class, and not an interface, so `Stack` itself is an implementation already. `Stack` extends `Vector` which is pretty much an (synchronized) array list.

Then there is a [`ArrayDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) which provides both stack operations such as [`push`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html#push%28E%29), [`pop`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html#pop%28%29) and queue operations such as [`addLast`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html#addLast%28E%29) and [`removeFirst`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html#removeFirst%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

[`ArrayDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) is a resizable-array implementation of the `Deque` interface, which is the recommended replacement of [`Stack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) (since Java6). And it also implements [`Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, look at `java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue` and `java.util.Stack`.  The source ships with the JDK.